# Sum last element in tuple where previous elements in tuple match

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a list of tuples in Python which contain three elements. The first two elements points to a location in an array and the final element is to be the value placed at that location. However, the same location sometimes appears more than once. In this case I want to add the values to be placed at that location. I have made a set from the list and sorted it. An extract from the list:

```
 (280, 9, 2),
 (280, 9, 4),
 (280, 9, 16),
 (280, 19, 1),
 (280, 19, 4),
 (280, 27, 32768),
 (280, 28, 262144),
 (280, 28, 524288),
 (281, 9, 2),
 (281, 9, 4),
 (281, 9, 8), etc.
```

As you can see at the 'location' (280,9) there are three final values; 2, 4 and 16, so the value to be placed there should be 22. The same would hold for (280, 19), (280, 28) and so on. Any idea as to how I can achieve this please?

Comment: Can't you simply accumulate in the location of the array? So (if) the array is initialilly 0, at the first `(280, 9, x)` you simply set (for example) `array[280][9] += x`. At the end of the four calls with `(280,9,)` you will have 22.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this before as I thought it would work, but for some reason it resulted in values been added to that I didn't want added to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are aware of `pandas` then make `dataframe` from these points and make groups on the basis of first and second value using `groupby`. Then calculate the sum of all thired values of each group

```
import pandas as pd

points = [(280, 9, 2),
 (280, 9, 4),
 (280, 9, 16),
 (280, 19, 1),
 (280, 19, 4),
 (280, 27, 32768),
 (280, 28, 262144),
 (280, 28, 524288),
 (281, 9, 2),
 (281, 9, 4),
 (281, 9, 8)]

points = pd.DataFrame(points).groupby([0,1])[2].sum().reset_index().to_numpy()
points = [tuple(p) for p in points]

print(points)
[(280, 9, 22), (280, 19, 5), (280, 27, 32768), (280, 28, 786432), (281, 9, 14)]
```

Comment: Superb, this works and I've been able to get out the array I want with all the values in place as they should be. Thanks very much. Sorry if I wasn't clear before, but it's fully working now.

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 alternative solutions.

1. Store the data of the first column and second column as dictionary key and use the third column as the dictionary value, updating the values everytime you add data.

```
# store and update data to dictionary
data_dict = {}
for x,y,value in data:
    data_dict[(x,y)] = data_dict.get((x,y),0) + value

# store data as tuples
new_data = []
for (x,y), value in data_dict.items():
    new_data.append((x,y,value))
    
print(new_data)
```

```
[(280, 9, 22), (280, 19, 5), (280, 27, 32768), (280, 28, 786432), (281, 9, 14)]
```

2. Make a new array named `new_data` and update the data based on its index (you have to store the data indices in a dictionary).

```
new_data = []
data_index = {}

current_index = 0
for x,y,value in data:
    if (x,y) in data_index.keys():
        # update data
        new_data[data_index[(x,y)]][2] += value
    else:
        # store the index location
        data_index[(x,y)] = current_index
        # update i for next iteration
        current_index += 1
        # Append the data to new_data as list
        # I'm using a list because tuples are immutable
        new_data.append([x,y,value])

# convert the data to tuples
new_data = [tuple(d) for d in new_data]
    
print(new_data)
```

```
[(280, 9, 22), (280, 19, 5), (280, 27, 32768), (280, 28, 786432), (281, 9, 14)]
```

3. Use `pandas` (It's a library built to deal with this kind of problem). You convert your data into a `pandas.DataFrame()`, `.groupby()` it based on the first column and second column (column 0 & 1), finally, `.sum()` the data. Use `.to_records()` if you want to convert the data back to a list of tuples.

```
import pandas as pd

new_data = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby([0,1]).sum().to_records()
print(new_data)
```

```
[(280,  9,     22) (280, 19,      5) (280, 27,  32768) (280, 28, 786432)
 (281,  9,     14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Numpy**

```
import numpy as np
list =   [(280, 9, 2),
 (280, 9, 4),
 (280, 9, 16),
 (280, 19, 1),
 (280, 19, 4),
 (280, 27, 32768),
 (280, 28, 262144),
 (280, 28, 524288),
 (281, 9, 2),
 (281, 9, 4),
 (281, 9, 8)]


arr = np.asarray(list)
for unique_first_col in np.unique(arr[:,0]):
    for unique_second_col in np.unique(arr[np.where(arr[:,0] == unique_first_col)][:,1]):
        your_arr[unique_first_col][unique_second_col] = arr[np.where((arr[:,0] == unique_first_col) & (arr[:,1] == unique_second_col))][:,2].sum()
```

Comment: Add an example of the desired output. That will help the others to understand and help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Method without `pandas`. Assuming you have got a list name as `k`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = [(key[0], key[1], sum(map(itemgetter(2),grp))) for key,grp in groupby(k, lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))]
```